# Sublime Text regex to find and replace whitespace between two xml or html tags?

Tags: html, regex, tags, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text and I need to come up with a regex that will find the whitespaces between a certain opening and closing tag and replace them with commas.

Example: Replace white space in

```
<tags>This is an example</tags>
```

so it becomes

```
<tags>This,is,an,example</tags>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will find instances of

```
<tags>...</tags>
```

with whitespace between the tags

```
(<tags>\S+)\W(.+</tags>)
```

This will replace the first whitespace with a comma

```
\1,\2
```

Open Find and Replace [OS X Cmd+Opt+F :: Windows Ctrl+H]

Use the two values above to find and replace and use the 'Replace All' option. Repeat until all the whitespaces are converted to commas.

The best answer is probably a quick script but this will get you there fairly fast without needing to do any coding.

Answer (score 11):

You have just to use a simple regex like:

```
\s+
```

And replace it with with a comma.

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/xB7hC7/1)**

[image]

Comment: I have hundreds of lines in about 50 xml files, I can't do one at a time. I need something that will locate only the spaces inside of the <tags></tags> tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace any one or more whitespace chunks in between two tags using a *single* regular expression:

```php
(?s)(?:\G(?!\A)|<tags>(?=.*?</tags>))(?:(?!</?tags>).)*?\K\s+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nkCXhB/1/). **Details**

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL inline modifier, makes `.` match line breaks
- `(?:\G(?!\A)|<tags>(?=.*?</tags>))` - either the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!\A)`) or (`|`) `<tags>` substring that is immediately followed with any zero or more chars, as few as possible and then `</tags>` (see `(?=.*?</tags>)`)
- `(?:(?!</?tags>).)*?` - any char that does not start a `<tags>` or `</tags>` substrings, zero or more occurrences but as few as possible
- `\K` - [match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html)
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces (**NOTE**: use `\s` if each whitespace must be replaced).

SublimeText settings:
[image]